# Using Find Command To Remove Old Backups

Tags: find

I have been using this command to remove old backups on my server:

```
find /backups/etcbak/ -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \; && find /backups/varlogsbak/ -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \; && find /backups/varmysqlbak/ -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

The above commands works great at removing actual files in the targeted directories.

My problem is:

How do I get the above command to also remove subdirectories?

(I added a mysql backupscript that creates subdirectories in the targeted directories based upon the current date).

I tried to adjust the above command as follows:

```
find /backups/etcbak/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \; && find /backups/varlogsbak/ -mtime +2 -exec rm -rf {} \; && find /backups/varmysqlbak/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \; && find /backups/varmongobak/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But it simply will not remove old subdirectories.

The goal is to delete files -and- directories that may exist in the targeted directories.

For example:

`/backups/etcbak/filename   (where "filename" is deleted after 7 days)`

and

`/backups/etcbak/dirname`  (where the subdir named "dirname" and its contents are also deleted after 7 days)

Anyone know how to crack this?  thx

Comment: What do you want to test the timestamp of, files or directories? Note that the timestamp on a directory only changes when you add something or delete something from that directory, not when you change a file in the directory. Also, note that the commands you present will delete directories that it will later try to enter.

Comment: @Kusalananda thx for the fb.  the first command never acutally removed the directories, it deleted backup that were greater than 7 days old (logs 2 days)... so I am a bit confused when you say it will delete directories it will later try to enter... I actually haven't had that problem with either command... I am just trying to figure out how to delete subdirectories and files inside the top level directories above....

Comment: I know the first command won't delete directories (because `rm` without `-r` does not delete directories), but it will try if a directory hasn't been changed recently (and you'll get errors from it). Your second command would try to delete `/backups/etcbak`, `/backups/varlogsbak`,   `/backups/varmysqlbak` and `/backups/varmongobak` as soon as nothing has been added or deleted from these directories in seven days (adding/deleting things in subdirectories does not affect the directory timestamps).

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. If a file, `/backups/varmongobak/dir/file` has not changed in a week, what do you want to delete? If a directory, `/backups/varmongobak/dir/subdir` hasn't had anything added to it, do you want to delete that directory and all subdirectories (even though files may have things changed in them)?  Are you trying to perform some sort of incremental backup in a single backup directory?

Comment: @Kusalananda  I edited my questioned and added an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: In your added examples, if a file in `/backups/etcbak/dirname/subdir` changed, would you want to keep that file until it was a week old, even though the timestamp on `/backups/etcbak/dirname` would be older (which it would be)?

Comment: No.. in the example /backups/etcbak/dirname/    ...the directory "dirname" and all of its contents is deleted after 7 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to delete files according to your criterion and then remove empty directories

```
find /backups/etcbak /backups/varmysqlbak /backups/varmongobak -depth -type f -mtime +7 -delete
find /backups/varlogsbak -depth -type f -mtime +2 -delete

find /backups/etcbak /backups/varlogsbak /backups/varmysqlbak /backups/varmongobak -mindepth 1 -depth type d -delete 2>/dev/null
```

Strictly speaking, `-depth` isn't required as it's implied by `-delete`, but I think it's useful to see it and be reminded that it's active

Comment: Appreciate the feedback.. I just the commands as written above, but the directories older than 7 days were not deleted... :-/  I am on ubuntu 20.04 if that mankes a difference

Comment: This code deletes empty directories, regardless of age. It specifically does not delete directories that contain files, regardless of the directories' age. Otherwise you could have a directory 10 days old that was scheduled for deletion but contained a file that was, say, only 3 days old. Deleting the directory would of necessity require deleting the underaged file

Comment: Thanks for the help... All seems to be working now